# Terraform Plan returns detailed exitcode 1 instead of 2 on successful plan

Tags: bash, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to do terraform plan for different directories in my repo using a bash script that is being called using GitHub action and then the plans will be added into PR comment.

But I am getting detailed exitcode 1 instead of 2 on the successful terraform plan.

```
for SERVICE in $STAGING_SERVICES; do
  pushd "${ENVIRONMENT_PATH}/staging/${SERVICE}" &>/dev/null

  # Initialize terraform
  terraform init &>/dev/null

  # Do a plan to see the changes
  TERRAFORM_CHANGES="$(terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -refresh=false -no-color -compact-warnings)"
  RETCODE=$?

  # echo "RETURN CODE: ${RETCODE}"
  if (( ${RETCODE} -eq 0 )); then
    echo "### No changes to be made ✅ [staging/${SERVICE}] "
  elif [[ ${RETCODE} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "### Error  [staging/${SERVICE}] 
<details><summary>Show Issues</summary>

\`\`\`
${TERRAFORM_CHANGES}
\`\`\`

</details>

"
  elif [[ ${RETCODE} -eq 2 ]]; then
    cat <<EOF
### Changes to be made ⚠️ [staging/${SERVICE}] 
<details><summary>Show Plan</summary>
\`\`\`
${TERRAFORM_CHANGES}
\`\`\`
</details>

EOF
  fi

  popd &>/dev/null
done
```

It is running taking 1 from detailed exitcode.
([image: Github comment])

One thing I am noticing, in the plan details it actually producing 2 but I don't know why from shell it brings detailed exitcode 1
[image: Plan details]

This is my yml code for Github Action workflow:

```
    - run: npm install execa

    - name: Run Terraform script and comment on PR
      uses: actions/github-script@v4
      if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
      env:
        CI_STDOUT: ${{ steps.ci.outputs.stdout}}
        CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL }}
        CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY }}
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        script: |
          const execa = require('execa')

          const { stdout } = await execa('/bin/bash', ['scripts/terraform_ci.sh', 'terraform/environments'])

          github.issues.createComment({
            issue_number: context.issue.number,
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            body: stdout
          })
```

Comment: Also, I don't know why in plan details it is putting debug and other statements.